# como envio para outro pagina a partir de botao desconfigurado?

Tags: php

nao estou conseguindo! tenho este botao que salvei do meu site antigo..
alguem consegue me dar uma luz?

minha estrutura html e a seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link href="file:///Users/deobran/Desktop/ml2/escolha%20frma%20de%20envio/endaddenvio_arquivos/spa.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="file:///Users/deobran/Desktop/ml2/escolha%20frma%20de%20envio/endaddenvio_arquivos/cart-core_ui__large-8a4dd5edfa.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="file:///Users/deobran/Desktop/ml2/escolha%20frma%20de%20envio/endaddenvio_arquivos/cho__large-1b07b8ca17.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

      <body> 
          <div data-js="shipping-options-region" class="shipping-options-container">
             <section data-js="shipping-options-group-0" class="delivery-options">
                 <div>
                    <div class="shipping-options-group">
                       <h3 class="block-title">!!!!</h3>
                       <div class="shipping-options-list-container">
                            <ul class="cart-package__options ui-list__content ui-list " data-js="shipping-options-list">
                                 <li class="ui-list__item ui-list__item--selected">
                                     <form data-id="shipping-option-104830550300001"   data-state="selected" data-js="shipping-option-form" class="shipping-option-form" method="post">

                                          <button type="submit"  name="selectedShippingOption" >

                        <div class="cart-package__option-button u-ripple-effect--active u-ripple-effect" >
                            <div class="cart-package__shipping-box">
                                 <div class="cart-package__shipping-header">
                                     <div data-id="shipping-option-name" class="cart-package__shipping__title">
                                         clique aqui!
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="cart-package__shipping__info cart-package__shipping__info-inline">
                                       imperdivel    
                                    </p>
                                 </div>
                             <span class="cart-package__shipping-price">
                             <span class="cart-package__shipping-price-container">
                             <span data-id="shipping-option-price-free" class="shipping-option-price price-free   u-link">


      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Não está claro, explica melhor

Comment: Faça a endentação do código antes de apresentar para alguém ou publicar na rede, é desagradável para um programador ver um código desorganizado. É como levar uma roupa suja para uma costureira consertar. 
A pergunta possui a tag *PHP* e não há um código em *PHP*. Então sua dúvida deve ser sobre *HTML*, coloque a tag correta. Seu `<form>`, que não aparece inicialmente por conta da má endentação, não possui a propriedade `action` cujo a função ao enviar, especifica onde entregar os dados do formulário.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro ao linkar um botão a uma pagina qualquer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399339/erro-ao-linkar-um-bot%c3%a3o-a-uma-pagina-qualquer)

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não possui código PHP, caso realmente seja somente o html, para enviar para outra página é necessário apenas trocar o button por um `<a href="link"></a>`

```
  <body> 
      <div data-js="shipping-options-region" class="shipping-options-container">
         <section data-js="shipping-options-group-0" class="delivery-options">
             <div>
                <div class="shipping-options-group">
                   <h3 class="block-title">!!!!</h3>
                   <div class="shipping-options-list-container">
                        <ul class="cart-package__options ui-list__content ui-list " data-js="shipping-options-list">
                             <li class="ui-list__item ui-list__item--selected">
                                 <form data-id="shipping-option-104830550300001"   data-state="selected" data-js="shipping-option-form" class="shipping-option-form" method="post">

                                      <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://google.com.br" type="submit"  name="selectedShippingOption" > Link </a>

                    <div class="cart-package__option-button u-ripple-effect--active u-ripple-effect" >
                        <div class="cart-package__shipping-box">
                             <div class="cart-package__shipping-header">
                                 <div data-id="shipping-option-name" class="cart-package__shipping__title">
                                     clique aqui!
                                </div>
                                <p class="cart-package__shipping__info cart-package__shipping__info-inline">
                                   imperdivel    
                                </p>
                             </div>
                         <span class="cart-package__shipping-price">
                         <span class="cart-package__shipping-price-container">
                         <span data-id="shipping-option-price-free" class="shipping-option-price price-free   u-link">


  </body>
```